# Nested Parameters/Values in POST Requests

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, input-filter

I have been thinking about a good way to handle nested/complex values in POST requests to a apigility resource.

For example, an order might contain a collection of order items in a single POST requested that is used to create an order. Both, order and order-item do exist as a resource. However, I would very much like to have only one request that would create order and order item entities. Handling that in the resource is not a problem, but I wonder how you would configure that resource (let´s call it order-place) using the apigiliy UI - or, if at all impossible, using the configuration. Applying validators and filters is one of the key features of apigility, and i´d like to keep using that, even for complex request data.

And before you ask, using an underscore to separate the values scopes, for example order_comment and order_item_comment should not be an option.

Any ideas?:)

Addition: A sample json request payload could look like this:

```
{
"created_at": "2000-01-01",
"amount" : "5000.00",
"address" : {
    "name": "some name",
    "street": "some street"
    ...
},
"items" : [
    {"productId":99,"qty":1}
    ...
]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample JSON sent to server? Hopefully structured in an ideal to you way.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Wilt's answer, I've found that the following code works as well:

```
# file path: /module/MyApi/config/module.config.php

// some other stuff

  'MyApi\\V1\\Rest\\MyRestService\\Validator' => array(
       'address' => array(
            0 => array(
                'name'     => 'name',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(),
                'validators' => array(),
            ),
            1 => array(
                'name'     => 'street',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(),
                'validators' => array(),
            ),
            'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter'
        ),
        'amount' => array(
            'name'       => 'amount',
            'required'   => true,
            'filters'    => array(),
            'validators' => array()
        )
```

The only problem I get is when `address` is passed as a field (string or numeric) rather then an array or object. In this case Apigility throws an exception:

> Zend\InputFilter\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Zend\InputFilter\BaseInputFilter::setData expects an array or Traversable argument; received string in /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/InputFilter/BaseInputFilter.php on line 175

Adding `address` as a further simple (required) field avoids the exception, but then Apigility doesn't see any difference whether we pass `address` as an array of `name` and `street` or a dummy string.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `ContentValidation` module then you can configure an input filter for the nested resources by assigning it to a variable. Then you have to add a type key (essential otherwise reusing the filter won't work). Now you are able to use this variable in your `input_filter_specs` and you can reuse the whole filter inside another filter. So something like this in your `config.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Application;

// Your address config as if it was used independently
$addressInputFilter => array(
    'name' => array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            //...
        )
        'validators' => array(
            //...
        )
    ),
    'street' => array(
        'name' => 'street',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            //...
        )
        'validators' => array(
            //...
        )
    ),
    // 'type' key necessary for reusing this input filter in other configs
    'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter'
),


'input_filter_specs' => array(
    // The key for your address if you also want to be able to use it independently
    'Application\InputFilter\Address'=> $addressInputFilter,
    // The key and config for your other resource containing a nested address
    'Application\InputFilter\ItemContainingAddress'=> array(
        'address' => $addressInputFilter,
        'amount' => array(
            'name' => 'amount',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                //...
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                //...
            )
        )
        //... your other fields
    )
)
```

Comment: This at least would allow me to apply filters and validators, that is true so far. But it does not use the features given by the apigility ui in terms of documentation and confugration. After some more research here i´m afraid it is just not possible. Maybe it´s time for a github project...:)